# c# console application formatting tried multiple ways but stumped

Tags: c#, formatting

Hey there it's my first semester of comp sci and we are making a renovation calculator and i have finished all the code it works properly and rounds but the formatting is supposed to look a certain way and i have no idea how to have it all line up

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlXgB.jpg(console
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvDhZ.jpg(code)

```
Console.WriteLine("           Packing Slip");
        Console.WriteLine("*******************************************");
        Console.WriteLine($"{wallrounded    }     ^ft. Wall area");
        Console.WriteLine($"{ceilingrounded }     ^ft. ceiling area");
        Console.WriteLine($"{gallons        }      gallons(s)  {paintoption   }  Paint       @  {paintcost    } =  {painttotal    }");
        Console.WriteLine($"{flooringrounded}     ^ft.         {flooringoption} Flooring     @  {flooringprice} =  {flooringcost  }");
        Console.WriteLine($"{casing         }      ft.                           casing      @   1.29           =  {casingcost    }");
        Console.WriteLine($"{baseboard      }      ft.                           baseboard   @   2.59           =  {baseboardcost }");
        Console.WriteLine("                                                                                          ======");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                                                 Net Total          =  {nettotal      }");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                                                 GST                =  {gst           }");
        Console.WriteLine($"                                                                 Total              =  {nettotal + gst}");
```

Comment: You can specify a width: `Console.WriteLine($"{wallrounded,10}^ft. Wall area");`, etc

Comment: I like what @JohnnyMopp said! This might be a useful addition to that. [Override the ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types)

Comment: so does that mean itd use 10 charcter spaces?

Comment: That example is using [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Now that you know some of the terms, feel free to do your own Google searches and experiments!